# Excel: Return value to the left of last matching string before a blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of repeated text strings, and I'm trying to find a way to return the last instance that item *before a blank cell* and return its corresponding date.  There may be instances of that string after the blank, but I'm only interested in returning the date field for the iteration before the first blank cell.

So from the data set linked below, if I am searching for Green, it would return 12/7/2018; Red, it would return 12/2/18; Blue, it would return 12/5/18; Yellow, it would return 12/4/2018

I do not have to accommodate the situation in which there is a blank before the first instance...there will always be data before the initial blank, so returning null is fine...

[image: Sample Data]

I've tried a handful of Index/Match combinations, but getting stuck on the Blank cell condition, to then back up to the last matching cell, and returning a value to it's left.  Am I thinking about this incorrectly?  Should I be starting with searching out the first blank, then searching up for a string from there?  Unfortunately, my excel knowledge is limited to what I need to learn to do the job at hand, and this one is vexing me.  I'm very vexed.

Comment: Please include your current formula attempts.

Comment: I have none to speak of, just cobbled-together combinations of INDEX and MATCH formulas that I tried in researching earlier that I have since deleted - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($C$1:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($C$1:$C$100="",0),0)-1)=E3),B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant.  Slapping my head, so simple, posted a solution as well but deleted after seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified formula

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(INDIRECT("B2:B"&MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(B2:B11),0))="APPLE"),A2:A11)
```

Make sure you enter it with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` so it looks like in the attached output.

[image]

Comment: The lookup function, especially the last item lookup is explained [here] (https://www.exceltip.com/excel-formula-and-function/vlookup-to-find-last-matching-value.html).

Comment: is it possible to use wild cards, or what would be an option for this?  Specifically, if using your data above, there was a category for APRICOT and I wanted to search for anything starting with "AP*" - this seems to not be possible in my editing on my source data, so wondering if its possible....